# Rotation screen wint navigation controller

Tags: ios, iphone, rotation, screen-rotation

Can I disable rotation for all screens neither one for iPhone.
And how can I do it?
I do a lot of combinations with initial portrate/landscape and follow methods but not get it.
If I have enable landscape in app settings all screens are rotates. I can not now use device, I test it on simulator.

```
 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
 {
return NO;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
 {
//Choose your available orientation, you can also support more tipe using the symbol |
//e.g. return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight)
return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait);
}
```

Comment: u want to disable screen on all screens?

Comment: and enable only on one

Comment: so you are saying: a>b>c>d all in portrait and >e in landscape??

Comment: a>b>c>d portrait, >e landscape and portrait with autorotation

Comment: with the code in my post my screen is autorotate...

Comment: did you find my answer helpful

Comment: yes and no. I have some libs in my app. they have nav VC and I have custom nav VC. Basically I disable and enable roration in nav VC and it implements in all child VC's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i ran into the same problem first of all check mark on all orientation in built setting>targets>deployment info.
then in your app delegate file implement this:

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window{

UIViewController *currentViewController = [self topViewController];

// Check whether it implements a dummy methods called canRotate
if ([currentViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(canRotate)]) {
    // Unlock landscape view orientations for this view controller
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
}

// Only allow portrait (standard behaviour)
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
```

}

```
-(UIViewController*)topViewController {
return [self topViewControllerWithRootViewController:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController];
```

}

```
- (UIViewController*)topViewControllerWithRootViewController:(UIViewController*)rootViewController{
```

if ([rootViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) 
{
        UINavigationController* aNavigationController = (UINavigationController*)rootViewController;

```
    return [self topViewControllerWithRootViewController:aNavigationController.visibleViewController];

}
else
{
    return rootViewController;
}
```

}

in your view controller(assume E) which you want to be in portrait/landscape..

add this:

```
//run time flag method
```

-(void)canRotate//also declare in header file
{

}

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
```

{
    return YES;
}

you are done.

for more info you can go to this [link](http://www.sebastianborggrewe.de/only-make-one-single-view-controller-rotate/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to subclass the UINavigationController and embed your ViewControllers in the navigation controller.

```
@implementation CustomNavigationController
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  supportedInterfaceOrientations:
//  Overridden to return the supportedInterfaceOrientations of the view controller
//  at the top of the navigation stack.
//  By default, UIViewController (and thus, UINavigationController) always returns
//  UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown when the app is run on an iPhone.
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return [self.topViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations]; 
}
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  shouldAutorotate
//  Overridden to return the shouldAutorotate value of the view controller
//  at the top of the navigation stack.
//  By default, UIViewController (and thus, UINavigationController) always returns
//  YES when the app is run on an iPhone.
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return [self.topViewController shouldAutorotate];
}
```

For each ViewController, you can override their `shouldAutorotate` and `supportedInterfaceOrientations` methods.

Comment: You will also want to implement (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation in the same manner